# Как в Rust передать элемент массива в качестве типа создаваемой структуры?

Tags: массивы, rust, типы

Каким образом можно передать один из элементов массива в качестве типа создаваемой структуры? И можно ли это вообще?
Попробовал набросать такой код:

```
const TYPES: [&str; 2] = ["Type1", "Type2"];

struct Type1;
struct Type2;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct StructA <T> {
    size: i32,
    struct_type: T,
}

fn main() {

    const B: &str = TYPES[1];

    let s: StructA <B> = StructA {
        size: 15,
        struct_type: B,
    };

    println!("{:?}", s.struct_type);
}
```

Компилятор ругается:

```
error[E0747]: constant provided when a type was expected
  --> src\main.rs:17:18
   |
17 |     let s: StructA <B> = StructA {
   |                     ^
```

Спасибо.

Comment: Вы пишите что-то крайне странное. Зачем вам вообще нужен `TYPES` и что мешает написать просто `StructA<Type2>`?

Comment: Возможно. Я просто пытался проверить, можно ли присваивать тип создаваемой структуре исходя из некоторых условий, определяемых "на лету".

Comment: «На лету» в программе не существует никакой полноценной информации о типах (разве что отдельные ошмётки вроде vtable для dyn trait), поэтому в общем случае — нельзя. Если у вас есть какая-то конкретная прикладная задача, можно попробовать подобрать какое-то индивидуальное решение для неё, но в общем случае в скомпилированной программе информация о типах теряется

Comment: Однако, исходя из моей личной практики, в большинстве случаев оказывается достаточно создать просто `enum` с описанием всех ожидаемых типов внутри него https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ad0ed04fd92e65a2e3d47c1a24237967

Comment: просто тип надо или убрать совсем, или написать туда правильный тип: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b8e8c51b97a8e3d1e891537977dfafe4 Но это ответ "в лоб", а если отвечать более разумно - вы делаете не то, что вам хочется.

Comment: ¿Зачем это проверять? rust является языком со статической типизацией.